# Wrong transfer of a file over Java socket

Tags: java, file, sockets, tcp, transfer

I am trying to transfer an XML file from a desktop server to an Android client but I get on the Android device just 1024 bytes of the entire file. My code is:

---

### Sending the file from the desktop server to the Android client:

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) filePianificazione.length()];

BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePianificazione));

bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

bufferedInputStream.close();

out.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

out.flush();
```

---

### Receiving of the file from the Android client to the server:

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

int bytesRead = in.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);

bos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you declare `byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];`

Then you're doing a single

```
int bytesRead = in.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
```

In your read code (Android client side), you're only reading 1024 bytes because that's the length of your input buffer, and you're only reading into it once. You need to have a `while` loop that'll continue to read from your input stream and then write that out until you reach EOF.

Something like:

```
while(in.available() > 0)
{
    int bytesRead = in.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was something like that and i had tried to do it, but it didn't work because I was using a BufferedOutputStream object instead of a FileOutputStream one.

Comment: You might want to also look into `BufferedInputReader` and other similar wrappers. They can make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Bzzt. This is a misuse of available(). Just read the input until EOS.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. I don't have too much experience with a raw `BufferedInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```